# Read paths from text file without newline string \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code which should do the following:
Read line by line, the paths from a text file -> Move into that path -> Get current working directory -> List all the files in that directory.

```
with open('pca_paths.txt', 'r') as pca_paths_file:
    for line in pca_paths_file:
        os.chdir(line)
        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        print("\nCurrent working directory is " + current_directory)
        pca_data_list = os.listdir('.')
        print(pca_data_list)
```

However, since each line in the text file ends with a \n, i get the following error:

```
No such file or directory: /home/user/path/ \n
```

Kindly suggest a way to read the paths without the newline string \n.
Thank you.

Comment: `line.strip()` ?

Comment: Do `os.chdir(line.strip())`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Rakesh and shmee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **line.strip()** instead of just **line**, that will remove unwanted newlines and spaces at the end. (I assume the error occurs on **os.chdir(line)**, you haven't specified where it gets raised)

Comment: Then line.strip() should help.

Comment: `line.strip()` may remove space characters that are part of the directory name itself. A more pedantic solution may be `line.rstrip('\n\r')`

Comment: I actually thought about that Tristan but remembered that directories usually don't allow trailing spaces, but I may be misremembering.